# Symfony2 shared/external assets

Tags: symfony, ezpublish

I am trying to use assets outside of the web folder and receiving 404 error messages. I have asset folders (/js, /css, /images) that reside in the www root folder and I tried to symlink those folders into my symfony web folder. I tried creating an alias for each in my apache config but that didn't work either. These resources are shared across multiple projects and I would like to keep from duplicating these assets.

Is this possible to symlink asset folders/files into the symfony web folder? I'm sure the easy answer is to redo the assets into the symfony way of doing things however these are legacy assets and still need to remain where they are.

My current set up is an ezpublish5 installation running in legacy mode with a vagrant development environment on windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can put any kind of files that you want to be publically accessible into the `web/` directory.

They will be accessible relative to that directory, so e.g. if you have a file `web/legacy/css/oldstuff.css`, it will be accessible at `www.example.com/legacy/css/oldstuff.css`.

Manually symlinking to a different should work, too. However, make sure that your links point to the correct location, especially after deploying.

Comment: I added the symlinks for each folder into web. So there is a /web/css/style.css and in my template files I have /css/style.css. Perhaps this issue lies within ezpublish/symfony2 or my virtual host configuration settings. If I change the environment to prod in the .conf file I get css + js files rendering but not any images. If I'm in the dev environment then I get nothing at all. I have run all the asset dumps etc.

Comment: Another possible cause of trouble could be your webserver config. Maybe you have some broken/obsolete rewrite rules or something.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the files within /web/css, /web/js and /web/images folders to work by updating my virtual host apache rewrite rules.

```
#RewriteCond %{ENV:ENVIRONMENT} "prod"
#RewriteRule ^/(css|js)/.*\.(css|js) - [L]

RewriteRule ^/css/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/js/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/images/ - [L]
```

So this works. I'm not sure if there is a better way or if this will effect the symfony asset management negatively for when I start refactoring legacy code into twig templates. My old templates did not take advantage of the twig asset tags and were standard html src includes.